# Cannot find type System.Runtime.InteropServices.StandardOleMarshalObject in module System.dll C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I tried to run my UWP project and it came out this error, where previously I run it was able to run smoothly. I don't know where the error is as it didn't show.

> Cannot find type System.Runtime.InteropServices.StandardOleMarshalObject in module System.dll

I searched around the internet and know that it might be the reference problem, here are the reference list that I have used:

> Analyzers
>
> Microsoft .NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
>
> MongoDB.Driver
>
> Newtonsoft.Json
>
> System.Windows.Forms
>
> TweetinviAPI
>
> Universal Windows

My application is about getting data from Twitter via TweetinviAPI and store them into Mongo database. Then analyze the data in terms of finding what they means. Also I'm using the latest Windows 10 Fall Creators Update so that the UWP would support .NET Standard 2.0, so I guess that's not the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely you meant ".NETStandard 2.0".   You are trying to write code that is neither "standard" nor "universal".  Very hard to imagine why you would even *need* StandardOleMarshalObject for a project like this, you can only get help if you don't force us to guess so much.

Comment: @HansPassant yes it was Standard 2.0 because previously I face problem with the MongoDB Driver with that, sorry I make things unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms` is not supported in UWP. Remove this dependency and refactor all code which depends on it.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I should check all the references before I implement any of those, my mistakes!